# Windows Emojis Picker does not appear

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, emoji

The Windows Emoji Picker is supposed to be displayed with the <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> (dot) or <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> (semi-colon) shortcut. But nothing is displayed, why?

Most <kbd>WIN</kbd> shortcuts are working, for example:

- <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (show Windows Explorer)
- <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (run an application)
- <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (show desktop)
  etc.

If relevant, Windows 10 Pro x64 (Build 19041.572) with `Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.31.0`.

#### UPDATE

Tested again after more than a year, and now <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> (and `;`) is working and displays the Emojis Picker. Multiple Windows updates have occurred since then, of course. Windows 10 (Build 19044.2846) is now installed. Presumably this was broken in an earlier version and Microsoft have now fixed the problem.

Comment: or install this app>>>>https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/emojis-picker/9nfq6j6h002j?activetab=pivot:overviewtab

Comment: using the dot on the numpad will not work, must use dot on the keyboard.

Comment: Which Windows 10 version?

Comment: @Moab: Neither dot works...